# Bootstrap 2 não faz a imagem flutuar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com um problema ao tentar colocar uma imagem do lado da outra com Bootstrap:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
     <li class="span4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
               <a href="#" class="thumbnail inner-border">

                   <img class="foto" src="uploaded/<?= $linha->img_nome; ?>">
               </a>
               <h3>Descrição da imagem: <?= $linha->titulo ?></h3>
               <p>Texto da pagina: <?= $linha->texto_da_imagem ?></p>
          </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Não sei porque a imagem não quer flutuar, seria a versão do Bootstrap?

Comment: Você colocou todas as imagens dentro da mesma tag <ul>?

Comment: sim são essas mesmas ai elas vem dinâmicamente, esse código está certo?

Comment: Poderia fornecer um exemplo funcional do problema usando jsfiddle ou stacksnippets (incluindo css e html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem duas opções, a primeira, pra preservar o seu código, é colocar tudo entre `row`s:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
<ul class="thumbnails">
     <li class="span4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
               <a href="#" class="thumbnail inner-border">

                   <img class="foto" src="uploaded/&lt;?= $linha-&gt;img_nome; ?&gt;">
               </a>
               <h3>Descrição da imagem: <!--?= $linha--->titulo ?&gt;</h3>
               <p>Texto da pagina: <!--?= $linha--->texto_da_imagem ?&gt;</p>
          </div>
     </li>
</ul> 
</div>
</div>
```

[Exemplo](http://www.bootply.com/CLR7nuBOnq)

A segunda, que eu aconselho, é retirar os `ul`, que não ficam legais dentro das rows, e ficar somente com a tabelação padrão:

```
<div class="row">  
  <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="thumbnail span4">
               <a href="#" class="thumbnail inner-border">
                   <img class="foto" src="uploaded/&lt;?= $linha-&gt;img_nome; ?&gt;">
               </a>
               <h3>Descrição da imagem: <!--?= $linha--->titulo ?&gt;</h3>
               <p>Texto da pagina: <!--?= $linha--->texto_da_imagem ?&gt;</p>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O importante é manter a dinâmica dentro do row, respeitando o limite de 12 estabelecido no bootstrap.

[Exemplo](http://www.bootply.com/kPOaVj3rsg)